# Автопротягивание формулы

Tags: таблицы

У меня есть формула `=СЛУЧМЕЖДУ(10000000; 99999999)` мне надо что бы при добавлении новой строки эта формула протягивалась автоматически. Строка пустая - нет формулы, добавилась строка - появилась формула.

Это надо в гугл таблице сделать

Comment: Добавление строки - это вообще что? Вставка пустой строки? скопированной строки? просто вставка некоего значения в ячейку строки, которая была пустая? что-то ещё?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.